# How to implement subcommand using App::Cmd module?

Tags: perl, command, command-line-interface

I use [App::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Cmd) for building my CLI apps.

Is it possible to implement subcommand like `docker network inspect` ? (assuming that `inspect` is subcommand)

I have following code for implementing command `foo bar`

```
$ cat bin/foo
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Foo;
Foo->run;

$ cat lib/Foo.pm 
package Foo;
use App::Cmd::Setup -app;
1;

$ cat lib/Foo/Command/bar.pm 
package Foo::Command::bar;
use App::Cmd::Setup -command;

sub execute {
    print "Hello world\n";
}

1;
```

I implemented subcommand `foo bar baz` by modifying `lib/Foo/Command/bar.pm` as:

```
sub execute {
    my ( $self, $opt, $args ) = @_;    
    my $subcommand = $args->[0];

    if ( $subcommand eq 'baz' ) {
        print "Subcommand baz is working\n";
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there any better way ?

Big minus of `$args->[0]` approach is that you can not auto generate `--help`  (`foo bar` will show same help as `foo bar baz`)

In other words, `App::Cmd` is sharpen for `<bin_name> <command> [-?h] [long options...]` call syntax, but I need `<bin_name> <command> <subcommand> [-?h] [long options...]` syntax.

P.S. I created [Github repository](https://github.com/pavelsr/app_cmd_demo/blob/subcommand/lib/Foo/Command/bar.pm) for experiments

Comment: App::Cmd supports subcommands though I haven't used it and I can't immediately find documentation for such.

Comment: I just found https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Cmd::Subdispatch::DashedStyle, but it's dashed style and it's not clear how to use it

Comment: An interesting module. Their [App::Cmd::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-Cmd/lib/App/Cmd/Tutorial.pod) flat out states that it "_handles commands with multiple subcommands_" but I couldn't find a single hint on how to do that. So I'd expect that there is no distinct API but you need to fish the capability out of what is described.  Perhaps contact the maintainer for pointers?

Comment: It seems to be [App::Cmd::Subdispatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Cmd::Subdispatch), with `$subdispatch->app;` where the `app` method "_returns the application that this subdispatch is a command of_." I guess it implements cascading of sorts, whereby what follows a command is in itself a command. Too bad it doesn't even say what `$subdispatch` is; it looks like you'll just have to play around with it to figure out how to use it.  Hope this helps at least some

Comment: @rjbs can you look on this question please ?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find some example code on Github ([[1]](https://github.com/jwbargsten/app-cmd-nested-example), [[2]](https://github.com/frioux/drinkup)) to figure this out.
For the `foo bar baz` use case, you need the following:

```
# Foo.pm is unchanged from your code

# Bar.pm is no longer a command module
$ cat lib/Foo/Command/Bar.pm 
package Foo::Command::Bar;

use base qw/App::Cmd::Subdispatch/;
use constant plugin_search_path => __PACKAGE__;

# no need for execute(), this module only dispatches subcommands
# abstract() and show_desc() are still supported

1;

# Finally, a subcommand like `baz` needs its own script Baz.pm 
# (mind the file location)
$ cat lib/Foo/Command/Bar/Baz.pm 
package Foo::Command::Bar::Baz;
use App::Cmd::Setup -command;

sub execute {
    print "Hello world\n";
}

1;
```